# On which level should I start/stop writing tests?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

So I started to use [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) and I really like the idea [to test user actions, **not** implementation details](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details).

What I'm really struggling with is where to start writing test ? To be more precise: on which level in the component tree I should start writing my tests?

Let's take the following code es an example:

#### OrderCreatePage

```
function CreateOrderPage() {
  const [stepOneFrom, setStepOneForm] = useState({});
  const [stepTwoFrom, setStepTwoForm] = useState({});
  const [stepThreeFrom, setStepThreeForm] = useState({});
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);

  const previousStep = () => {
    setStep(prev => prev - 1);
  }

  const nextStep = () => {
    setStep(prev => prev + 1);
  }

  const createOrder = () => {
    endpoint.createOrder({
      stepOneForm,
      stepTwoForm,
      stepThreeForm
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {step === 1 && 
        <StepOne
          form={stepOneForm}
          onNextStep={nextStep}
          onFormChange={setStepOneForm}
        />
       }
      {step === 2 && 
        <StepTwo
          form={stepTwoForm}
          onNextStep={nextStep}
          onPreviousStep={previousStep}
          onFormChange={setStepTwoForm}
        />
       }
      {step === 2 && 
        <StepTwo
          form={stepTwoForm}
          onPreviousStep={previousStep}
          onCreateOrder={createOrder}
          onFormChange={setStepTwoForm}
        />
       }
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### StepOne

```
function StepOne(props) {
  const isValidForm() => {
    return // do some checks on props.form
  }

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    if(isValidForm()){
      props.onNextStep();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ArticlesForm form={props.form} onFormChange={props.onFormChange}/> // StepTwo and StepThree e.g. have DeliveryForm and PaymentForm
      <button onClick={props.nextStep}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For `StepTwo` and `StepThree`, just imagine them to be similar to `StepOne`.

`ArticleForm` in the above example is declaring all the input fields etc. and is updating the form values.

Think of all components to be much more complex and don't take this example to serious. In general there are 3 level to write the tests (from lowest to highest level)

- **Form-level** aka `ArticleForm`: test if form is updated properly
- **Step-level** aka `StepOne`: test step independently from other steps, ensure that you are only allowed to go to next step when form is valid
- **Page-level** aka `OrderCreatePage`: test transitions of steps (including validation checks) and check if you can create the order

**So where to start testing here?**

If you write test for `ArticleForm` then you don't test validation, thus you need to write tests for `StepOne`. If you already wrote test for `ArticleForm` you would need to basically copy the logic of filling the input fields from that test which make `ArticleFrom` tests kind of useless. Okay let's skip `ArticleForm` tests then.

For the transitions you need to test `OrderCreatePage` now. This time you need to copy the logic of entering valid/invalid data from `StepOne` (and `StepTwo`, `StepThree`) tests, otherwise you are not able to proceed/check transitions.
So just remove the `StepOne` (and `StepTwo`, `StepThree`) tests.

But this result in a big test file for `OrderCreatePage` and that's not anywhere close to a unit test any more.

I would really appreciate any help here, because I always end up with this kind of thoughts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no formula for writing good and efficient tests, some measure coverage and then you should start testing the form-level to reach a good coverage percentage.

I like the approach of the author of the library you are using (react-testing-library)  https://kentcdodds.com/blog/write-tests

**Write tests. Not too many. Mostly integration.**

With your example I would try to look at it not from the code perspective, but from a user perspective :

happy flow : User should be able to complete all steps and submits the form (some mocking might be necessary there)

edge case: User should not be able to create order if not all fields are completed / step not validated etc.

In general there are many right answers to this question so keep an open mind, experiment and learn, there is no silver bullet here

Comment: actually very good blog/video! But if I only look at user perspective I almost always end up testing applications on a page level.. maybe it's just the application I work on atm and maybe it's just the best approach in this case ..

Comment: I think with this approach you will get the most ROI